# Cannot understand CLRS Problem 4-2 case 2

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, clrs

The question:

> **4-2 Parameter-passing costs**
>
> Throughout this book, we assume that parameter passing during procedure calls takes constant time, even if an N-element array is being passed. This assumption is valid in most systems because a pointer to the array is passed, not the array itself.
>   This problem examines the implications of three parameter-passing strategies:
>
> 1. An array is passed by pointer. Time Theta(1)
>
> **2. An array is passed by copying. Time Theta(N), where N is the size of the array.**
>
> 3. An array is passed by copying only the subrange that might be accessed by the called procedure. Time Theta(q-p+1) if the subarray A[p..q] is passed.
>
> a. Consider the recursive binary search algorithm for finding a number in a sorted array (see Exercise 2.3-5 ). Give recurrences for the worst-case running times of binary search when arrays are passed using each of the three methods above, and give good upper bounds on the solutions of the recurrences. Let N be the size of the original problem and n be the size of a subproblem.
>
> b. Redo part (a) for the MERGE-SORT algorithm from Section 2.3.1.

I have trouble understanding how to solve the recurrence of case 2 where arrays are passed by copying for both algorithms.

Take the binary search algorithm of case 2 for example, the recurrence most answers give is **T(n)=T(n / 2)+Theta(N)**. I have no trouble about that.

Here is an answer I find online that looks correct:

> T(n)
>
> = T(n/2) + cN
>
> = 2cN + T(n/4)
>
> = 3cN + T(n/8)
>
> = Sigma(i = 0 to lgn - 1) (2^i cN / (2^i))
>
> = cNlgn
>
> = Theta(nlgn)

I have trouble understanding how the second last line can result in the last line's answer. Why not represent it in Theta(Nlgn)? And how can N become n in the Theta notation?

N and n feel somewhat connected. I have trouble understanding their connection and how that is applied in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that N represents full array length and n is current chunk size.

But formulas really exploit initial value only, when you start from full length `n=N` - for example, look at `T(n/4)` for `T(N/4)`, so `n===N` everywhere.

In this case you can replace n with N.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will not be very theoretical, but maybe this "more empirical" approach will help you figure it out. Also check [Master Theorem (analysis of algorithms)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) for easier analysis of recursive algorithms complexity

Let's solve the binary search first:

1. By pointer

   `O(logN)` - acts like an iterative binary search, there will be `logN` calls each having `O(1)` complexity
2. Copying the whole array

   `O(NlogN)` - since for each of the `logN` calls of the function we copy `N` elements
3. Copying only the accessed subarray

   `O(N)` - this one is not that obvious, but can be easily seen that the copied subarrays will be of length, `N`, `N/2`, `N/4`, `N/8` .... and summing all this terms will be `2*N`

Now for the merge sort algorithm:

1. `O(NlogN)` - the same method as for `a3`, the iterated subarrays will be of lengths `N`, `(N/2, N/2)`, `(N/4, N/4, N/4, N/4)` ...
2. `O(N^2)` - we make `2*N` calls of the sorting function and each has a complexity of `O(N)` for copying the whole array
3. `O(NlogN)` - we will copy only the subarrays that we will iterate over, so the complexity will be as in `b1`